# I am having weird issues in SAS

Tags: sas

I need to write SAS code that divides the dataset into separate groups: With my code I get a extra period. I am not sure what I am missing. Could I have someone look at my code?

Comment: Here is my sample code: data want;
  set WORK.IMPORT;
where date between '01jan1948'd and '31dec1969'd; 
run;

Comment: Could you explain what you mean when you say you are getting an extra period? An extra time period?

Comment: It says it is getting: Variable date is not on file WORK.IMPORT. But I do see it in the WORK.IMPORT table.

Comment: It sounds like the date variable may be called something other than date. You can use proc contents to get a full list of the variables in your dataset.